# Python .join() format error

Tags: python, string, list, join

I'll start by saying I'm new with Python. I've been working on a Discord bot and I am stuck currently.

```
 list = ['brown', 'polar', 'grizzly', 'sun', 'kodiak']
 print("\nbear ".join(list))
```

This currently prints:

```
 brown
 bear polar
 bear grizzly
 bear sun
 bear kodiak
```

I'm confused as why `brown` isn't included in joining the list so it'd `bear brown`. I'm assuming I am placing `bear` in the wrong place, I'm just not sure where. Any help is greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for quite some time now. Thanks again.

Comment: Because your join starts with a `'\n'`.

Comment: `str.join` puts the delimiter *between* the items in the iterable, not *around* them.

Comment: Try adding `'teddy'` into list as the first element. Observe what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was already said that the delimiter is inserted between each element not added to each element.

However you can easily create a new list with the correctly added `bear`, for example:

```
>>> lst = ['brown', 'polar', 'grizzly', 'sun', 'kodiak']
>>> newlst = [item + ' bear' for item in lst]
>>> print('\n'.join(newlst))
brown bear
polar bear
grizzly bear
sun bear
kodiak bear
```

This adds a `bear` to **each** list item and then inserts a newline **between** the items.

You can also prepend it to each list item:

```
>>> newlst = ['bear ' + item for item in lst]
>>> print('\n'.join(newlst))
bear brown
bear polar
bear grizzly
bear sun
bear kodiak
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use `join` like this because you want to add `bear` & newline at the end of *each* line. You can `join` a list of properly formatted strings with empty strings:

```
"".join(map("{} bear\n".format,['brown', 'polar', 'grizzly', 'sun', 'kodiak']))
```

gives:

```
'brown bear\npolar bear\ngrizzly bear\nsun bear\nkodiak bear\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @jonrsharpe mentioned in the comment, `.join()` puts the separator in between items. To achieve what you're going for, you can use the following instead:

```
for item in list:
    print("bear", item)
```

Btw, I'd advise not to use `list` as a variable name, since that's the keyword you'd use to convert something to a list.